# jq: tidy up mapping expression

Tags: jq

My `jq` extract expression is getting too much large and I'm getting unconfortable using it:

```
jq -r '[.id,.meta.lastUpdated,.identifier[0].use, .identifier[0].system, .identifier[0].value, .identifier[1].use, .identifier[1].system, .identifier[1].value, .identifier[2].use, .identifier[2].system, .identifier[2].value, .identifier[2].assigner.reference, .active, .name[0].use, .name[0].text, .name[0].given[0], .name[0].family, .name[0]._family.extension[0].valueString, .address[0].extension[0].valueString, .address[0].type, (.address[0].line[]? | select(. | contains("TV^")) | split("^")[1]) // null, (.address[0].line[]? | select(. | contains("NV^")) | split("^")[1]) // null, (.address[0].line[]? | select(. | contains("NVI^")) | split("^")[1]) // null, .address[0].city, .address[0].state, .address[0].postalCode, .address[0].country, .qualification[0].code.coding[0].system, .qualification[0].code.coding[0].code] | @csv' practitioners-pre.json > practitioners-pre.csv
```

Is there any way tidy it up a bit?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to edit and present the query better (e.g. adding line-breaks or even putting it in its own file and passing it via `--from-file`), or ways to write this particular query more concisely? If the latter, it would be helpful to format it into multiple lines to make it easy to read, and to explain what it's doing along with example inputs and outputs. Perhaps you have in your mind a simple description of what you want it to do but you just don't know how to express that simply in jq... in which case, please tell us so that we aren't left trying to infer it from the jq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can add line breaks and remove  `. |`

```
[
   .id,
   .meta.lastUpdated,
   .identifier[0].use,
   .identifier[0].system,
   .identifier[0].value,
   .identifier[1].use,
   .identifier[1].system,
   .identifier[1].value,
   .identifier[2].use,
   .identifier[2].system,
   .identifier[2].value,
   .identifier[2].assigner.reference,
   .active,
   .name[0].use,
   .name[0].text,
   .name[0].given[0],
   .name[0].family,
   .name[0]._family.extension[0].valueString,
   .address[0].extension[0].valueString,
   .address[0].type,
   ( .address[0].line[]? | select( contains( "TV^"  ) ) | split( "^" )[1] ) // null,
   ( .address[0].line[]? | select( contains( "NV^"  ) ) | split( "^" )[1] ) // null,
   ( .address[0].line[]? | select( contains( "NVI^" ) ) | split( "^" )[1] ) // null,
   .address[0].city,
   .address[0].state,
   .address[0].postalCode,
   .address[0].country,
   .qualification[0].code.coding[0].system,
   .qualification[0].code.coding[0].code
] | @csv
```

We can also move the address line searching logic into a function. With the code isolated, it's easier to make it better. In the process, I improved it to split first, and to handle multiple matching lines better. (You may need to adjust the select`.)

```
def addr_special_field($field):
   [ .line[]? | split("^") | select( .[0] == $field ) ] | .[0][1]?;

[
   .id,
   .meta.lastUpdated,
   .identifier[0].use,
   .identifier[0].system,
   .identifier[0].value,
   .identifier[1].use,
   .identifier[1].system,
   .identifier[1].value,
   .identifier[2].use,
   .identifier[2].system,
   .identifier[2].value,
   .identifier[2].assigner.reference,
   .active,
   .name[0].use,
   .name[0].text,
   .name[0].given[0],
   .name[0].family,
   .name[0]._family.extension[0].valueString,
   .address[0].extension[0].valueString,
   .address[0].type,
   ( .address[0] | addr_special_field( "TV"  ) ),
   ( .address[0] | addr_special_field( "NV"  ) ),
   ( .address[0] | addr_special_field( "NVI" ) ),
   .address[0].city,
   .address[0].state,
   .address[0].postalCode,
   .address[0].country,
   .qualification[0].code.coding[0].system,
   .qualification[0].code.coding[0].code
] | @csv
```

This is long, but at least it's readable. Another thing we could do is factor out common terms, though I'm not sure it truly helps.

```
def addr_special_field($field):
   [ .line[]? | split("^") | select( .[0] == $field ) ] | .[0][1]?;

[
   .id,
   .meta.lastUpdated,
   ( .identifier[0] | .use, .system, .value ),
   ( .identifier[1] | .use, .system, .value ),
   ( .identifier[2] | .use, .system, .value, .assigner.reference ),
   .active,
   ( .name[0] | .use, .text, .given[0], .family, ._family.extension[0].valueString ),
   ( .address[0] |
      .extension[0].valueString,
      .type,
      addr_special_field( "TV"  ),
      addr_special_field( "NV"  ),
      addr_special_field( "NVI" ),
      .city,
      .state,
      .postalCode,
      .country
   ),
   ( .qualification[0].code.coding[0] | .system, .code )
] | @csv
```